# Uncaught ReferenceError: registerMinorEditInputEvents is not define facing js issue Backpack\EditableColumns

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-backpack

I am facing an issue while applying Editable Columns  on my Crud,

Following the https://backpackforlaravel.com/products/editable-columns

when I change columns in my Crud controller for the field

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests\VendorsRequest;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;
use \Backpack\EditableColumns\Http\Controllers\Operations\MinorUpdateOperation;

/**
 * Class VendorsCrudController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers\Admin
 * @property-read \Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel $crud
 */
class VendorsCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;

    /**
     * Configure the CrudPanel object. Apply settings to all operations.
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function setup()
    {
        CRUD::setModel(\App\Models\Vendors::class);
        CRUD::setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/vendors');
        CRUD::setEntityNameStrings('vendors', 'vendors');
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the List operation is loaded.
     * 
     * @see  https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-list-entries
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupListOperation()
    {
        CRUD::column('vendor_name');
        //CRUD::column('description');
         CRUD::addColumn([
        'name'             => 'description',
        'type'             => 'editable_text',
        'label'            => 'description',

        // Optionals
        'underlined'       => true, // show a dotted line under the editable column for differentiation? default: true
        'min_width'        => '120px', // how wide should the column be?
        'select_on_click'  => false, // select the entire text on click? default: false
        'save_on_focusout' => false, // if user clicks out, the value should be saved (instead of greyed out)
        'on_error' => [
            'text_color'          => '#df4759', // set a custom text color instead of the red
            'text_color_duration' => 0, // how long (in miliseconds) should the text stay that color (0 for infinite, aka until page refresh)
            'text_value_undo'     => false, // set text to the original value (user will lose the value that was recently input)
        ],
        'on_success' => [
            'text_color'          => '#42ba96', // set a custom text color instead of the green
            'text_color_duration' => 3000, // how long (in miliseconds) should the text stay that color (0 for infinite, aka until page refresh)
        ],
        'auto_update_row' => true, // update related columns in same row, after the AJAX call?
    ]);
        CRUD::column('created_at');
        CRUD::column('updated_at');

        /**
         * Columns can be defined using the fluent syntax or array syntax:
         * - CRUD::column('price')->type('number');
         * - CRUD::addColumn(['name' => 'price', 'type' => 'number']); 
         */
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Create operation is loaded.
     * 
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-create
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        CRUD::field('vendor_name');
        CRUD::field('description');

        /**
         * Fields can be defined using the fluent syntax or array syntax:
         * - CRUD::field('price')->type('number');
         * - CRUD::addField(['name' => 'price', 'type' => 'number'])); 
         */
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Update operation is loaded.
     * 
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-update
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        $this->setupCreateOperation();
    }
}
```

But I get a JSissue   Uncaught ReferenceError: registerMinorEditInputEvents is not defined

shown in the attached image and the version of all installed packaged

#### PHP VERSION:

PHP 8.1.17 (cli) (built: Mar 14 2023 23:07:43) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.17, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

#### LARAVEL VERSION:

10.15.0.0

#### BACKPACK PACKAGE VERSIONS:

backpack/backupmanager: v5.0.0
backpack/basset: 1.0.2
backpack/crud: 6.1.0
backpack/demo: dev-main
backpack/editable-columns: 3.0.1
backpack/filemanager: 3.0.2
backpack/generators: v4.0.2
backpack/logmanager: v5.0.0
backpack/medialibrary-uploaders: 1.0.1
backpack/menucrud: v4.0.1
backpack/newscrud: v5.0.0
backpack/pagemanager: 3.2.0
backpack/permissionmanager: 7.0.0
backpack/pro: 2.0.9
backpack/revise-operation: 2.0.0
backpack/settings: 3.1.0
backpack/theme-coreuiv2: 1.1.4
backpack/theme-coreuiv4: 1.0.5
backpack/theme-tabler: 1.0.6
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's failing is because JS (common.js) is not being properly loaded.

Please make sure you have `APP_URL` correctly set in your `.env` file.

If you do, please make sure you linked the storage folder with: `php artisan storage:link` and clear all the caches: `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan view:clear`.

Cheers